# List all available job positions using the API

Tags: api, query, php

I am very new to Salesforce tools and its inner workings. I was asked to recreate our company's Carrers page, that right now is a SF Site loaded inside an iframe on our website. The idea is to directly access all the information and display it with a better layout and.

I am using PHP to access the SF API and retrieve all job positions available. Then the user will be able to click on a specific job to see its details and apply to it.

```
define("USERNAME", "something@company.com");
define("PASSWORD", "password");
define("SECURITY_TOKEN", "1234567890123456789012345");

require_once ('sf-php-toolkit/soapclient/SforceEnterpriseClient.php');

$mySforceConnection = new SforceEnterpriseClient();
$mySforceConnection->createConnection("enterprise.wsdl.xml");
$mySforceConnection->login(USERNAME, PASSWORD.SECURITY_TOKEN);

echo '<h3>Testing...</h3>'.PHP_EOL;

$query = 'SELECT Name FROM ts2__Job__c';

try {
    $response = $mySforceConnection->query($query);
}
catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
}

echo "<p>Results of query '$query'</p>".PHP_EOL;

foreach ($response->records as $record) {
    echo $record->Name . "<br>".PHP_EOL;
}
```

The code above returns the following error:

```
Exception: INVALID_TYPE: SELECT Name FROM ts2__Job__c ^ ERROR at Row:1:Column:18 sObject type 'ts2__Job__c' is not supported. If you are attempting to use a custom object, be sure to append the '__c' after the entity name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.
```

The thing is, I am not sure that this `ts2__Job__c` is correct table to retrieve the data from. I didn't find it on the `https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_list.htm` reference, probably because it is a Custom Object.

And this is the WSDL XML code for the same object:

```
<complexType name="ts2__Job__c">
    <complexContent>
        <extension base="ens:sObject">
            <sequence>
                <element name="ActivityHistories" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" type="tns:QueryResult" />
                <element name="AttachedContentDocuments" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" type="tns:QueryResult" />
                <element name="Attachments" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" type="tns:QueryResult" />
                <element name="CombinedAttachments" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" type="tns:QueryResult" />
                <element name="CreatedBy" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" type="ens:User" />
                <element name="CreatedById" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" type="tns:ID" />
                <element name="CreatedDate" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" type="xsd:dateTime" />
                <element name="Date_Opened__c" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" type="xsd:date" />
                <element name="DuplicateRecordItems" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" type="tns:QueryResult" />
                <element name="Events" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" type="tns:QueryResult" />
                <element name="FeedSubscriptionsForEntity" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" type="tns:QueryResult" />
                <element name="Feeds" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" type="tns:QueryResult" />
                <element name="Histories" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" type="tns:QueryResult" />
                <element name="IsDeleted" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" type="xsd:boolean" />
                <element name="LastActivityDate" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" type="xsd:date" />
                <element name="LastModifiedBy" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" type="ens:User" />
                <element name="LastModifiedById" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" type="tns:ID" />
                <element name="LastModifiedDate" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" type="xsd:dateTime" />
                <element name="LastReferencedDate" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" type="xsd:dateTime" />
                <element name="LastViewedDate" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" type="xsd:dateTime" />
                <element name="LookedUpFromActivities" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" type="tns:QueryResult" />
                <element name="Name" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" type="xsd:string" />
                <element name="Notes" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" type="tns:QueryResult" />
                <element name="NotesAndAttachments" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" type="tns:QueryResult" />
                <element name="OpenActivities" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" type="tns:QueryResult" />
                <element name="Owner" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" type="ens:Name" />
                <element name="OwnerId" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" type="tns:ID" />
                <element name="ProcessInstances" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" type="tns:QueryResult" />
                <element name="ProcessSteps" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" type="tns:QueryResult" />
                <element name="RecordAssociatedGroups" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" type="tns:QueryResult" />
                <element name="RecordType" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" type="ens:RecordType" />
                <element name="RecordTypeId" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" type="tns:ID" />
                <element name="SystemModstamp" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" type="xsd:dateTime" />
                <element name="Tags" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" type="tns:QueryResult" />
                <element name="Tasks" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" type="tns:QueryResult" />
                <element name="TopicAssignments" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" type="tns:QueryResult" />
                <element name="UserRecordAccess" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" type="ens:UserRecordAccess" />
                ... more elements ...
            </sequence>
        </extension>
    </complexContent>
</complexType>
```

Any idea about what am I doing wrong?

Comment: check for Job__c under setup-> create -> Object what is the API name you have

Comment: @Himanshu it shows `API Name ts2__Job__c`. Could this error be related to user's permission to access the API? http://sforcehacks.blogspot.com.br/2013/11/invalidsobjectfault-invalidtype.html

Comment: yes. please check the object permission. it seems that this is part of a managed package. please check the license.

Comment: @Rodrigo In salesforce "__c" is automatically appended to the API name of every custom object. Other than that it CANNOT contain two consecutive unserscores. Your does - between "ts2" and "job" . So please check it.  Thanks

Comment: @Himanshu I didn't find the place to check or set the permissions of the Custom Object. I think I will open a support ticket with the Salesforce guys.

Comment: got to setup->profiles-> select profile and check for object permissions

Comment: Tks @Himanshu. It's not that simple when you don't know what you are looking for. Our guy from HR helped find that the path is Setup > Manage Users > Users > click on user > Managed Packages > Assign Licenses > Add the JS2 package. Then my user which was already on a Custom Profile with Job Orders permission, got access to the `ts2__Job__c` thing.

Comment: @Stygon thanks for the help, but in the end the entire string `ts2__Job__c` worked. Any other variation of it, by removing the prefix or suffix, does not work.

Comment: great!! so it means that it is working now?

Comment: Yes it is! I will later add a answer with all the information I gathered. Next step is to discover where is the ID of each item and then show its details on a new page. One problem at a time :-)